# Set up hardforks parameters in parity JSON chain spec file for private network

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, testnets, chainspec

I want to set up a private network for tests using parity, which will function in the same way as the current mainnet, but with very low block mining complexity. Is Is it true that for this I need to manually set the values of the eip{number}Transition fields from [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/master/ethcore/res/ethereum/foundation.json) config file to zero? And is it true that I don't need to specify the parameters associated with DAO hard fork for my local testnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you don’t have to .. but those transition numbers indicate when those eips come into play. If you are going to use any of the features then it makes sense to set them to kick in from the beginning.

You also don’t need the dao transition since in your private blockchain the dao never happened